# Collection View Within TableViewCell as XIB

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uistoryboard

So I have a collectionView in a tableViewCell.

It all worked fine, when the tableViewCell was in my Storyboard.

I decided to move the tableViewCell to its own XIB because the storyboard was lagging. Now it gives the error ->

> **** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view
>   of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier TagCellReview -
>   must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a
>   prototype cell in a storyboard'****

In CellForRowAtIndexPathTableView -->

```
       static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"FeedReviewCell";
       ReviewTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            // Configure the cell...
            if (cell == nil) {
                NSArray *customCell = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ReviewTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
                cell = [customCell objectAtIndex:0];
                cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
                cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
            }
        cell.tagsCollectionView.delegate = self;
        cell.tagsCollectionView.dataSource = self;
```

cellForItemAtIndexPath CollectionView -->

```
        TagsCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"TagCellReview" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.tagLabel.text = [reviewSection.serviceTags objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        return cell;
```

Any idea why this happens? Possible solutions?

Comment: where did you design your collectionview cell? xib or storyboard?

Comment: You forgot to set class in your nib of Collection view cell

Comment: i think you need to register class for collection view cell and/or register nib for collection view cell if you designed it in xib.

Comment: Yup! That worked! Moved the collectionViewCell to a new XIB and did             [cell.tagsCollectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"TagsCollectionViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"TagCell"];

Comment: Can you write an answer, I will mark it correct for future users!

Comment: Why do you have a collection view inside a tableView cell? I'm not trying to criticize your code too harshly, as you can obviously do whatever you please, but it seems overly complicated. It might be easier to use a collection view and divide it up into different sections in order to achieve similar functionality with much less complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to register class for collection view cell if the cell is in Storyboard and/or register nib for collection view cell if you designed the cell in xib.

```
//For Storyboard

    [cell.collectionView registerClass:[TagsCollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"TagsCollectionViewCell"];

// register nib for XIB
    [cell.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"TagsCollectionViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"TagsCollectionViewCell"];
```